# cover background image and off-canvas panel

Tags: css, background-image, panel, cover

I am using this simple code to adjust a full page background image to my element:

```
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Everything works great but now I have the problem that in Firefox V30 for example the background-image does not go to the left if the page shows a off-canvas panel from the right. The div which contains the background-image will of course be animated to the left but the background-image will not.

What are solutions to fix this issue?

Comment: try changing cover to `background-size: contain;`

Comment: that does not change anything